# How to change add margin bottom and margin right if some condition true using typescript and react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have the componet like below, when isOpen state true then should add margin-top 0, margin-bottom: 0, margin-right and margin-left: 4px. if isOpen state false then add margin-right: 4px and margin-bottom: 4px.

below is my code,

```
function Parent() {
    
    return (
        <Wrapper isOpen={isOpen}/>
            //Some content
        </Wrapper>
    );
}

const Wrapper = styled(somediv)<{ isOpen: boolean | undefined;}>`
    width: ${props => (props.isOpen ? '32px' : '40px')};
    margin: 0 4px; //should modify this based on isOpen true or not.
`;
```

Could someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean add on the existing `0 4px` values?

Comment: yes if isOpen false then apply 0 4px as marginn values. if isOpen true then apply only margin-bottom and margin-right as 4px

Comment: Think it's pretty straightforward. You've quite a few answers already ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same styled component approach as you used.
It will work like following:

```
function Parent() {
    
    return (
        <Wrapper isOpen={isOpen}/>
            //Some content
        </Wrapper>
    );
}

const Wrapper = styled(somediv)<{ isOpen: boolean | undefined;}>`
    width: ${props => (props.isOpen ? '32px' : '40px')};
    margin: ${props => (props.isOpen ? '0 4px' : '0 4px 4px 0')};
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
     <Wrapper isOpen={isOpen} style={{ isOpen===true? 
  {marginRight:'0px';marginLeft:'4px'} : {marginRight:'4px';marginLeft:'4px';} }}/>
            //Some content
        </Wrapper>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way would be to create two object each one with different properties and add them with inline styles.

```
const styles1 = {};
const styles2 = {};    
<Wrapper style={{isOpen ? styles1 : styles2}}/>
            //Some content
        </Wrapper>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly but using ternary operator it should look like this

```
const Wrapper = styled(somediv)<{ isOpen: boolean | undefined;}>`
    width: ${props => (props.isOpen ? '32px' : '40px')};
    margin: ${props => (props.isOpen ? '0 4px' : '0 4px 4px 0')}
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use className instead of inline-styling, I recommend using [makeStyles from Material UI](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/) as below

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/styles
```

and then,

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  myClass: {
    marginBottom: isOpen => isOpen ? 4 : 0,
    marginTop: 4,
    width: isOpen => isOpen ? 32 : 40
  }
}))

const Parent = () => {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false)
  const classes = useStyles(isOpen)

  return <div className={classes.myClass} />
}
```

Then you can use the same for other attributes and classes.